# Request Handler with @cached_property in GAE with python

Tags: python, google-app-engine

Sorry for nerd question, but I spent 2 days but cannot find any solution.

This is my route.py configuration

```
app = WSGIApplication(
    routes=[
        Route("/account", handler="app.account.Settings")
    ]
)
```

I created a Handler like that (which required login)

```
@HealthPortRequestHandler.login_required
class Settings(HealthPortRequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.render("account/settings.html")
```

And create login_required validation method

```
@cached_property
    def check_user_logged_in(self):
        if self.request.cookies.get("User"):
            user_id = self.read_cookie("User")
            if user_id:
                from models.users import Users
                return Users.get_by_id(int(user_id))
            else:
                return None
        return None

    @staticmethod
    def login_required(handler):
        def check_login(self, *args, **kwargs):
            if self.check_user_logged_in:
                return handler(self, *args, **kwargs)
            else:
                return self.redirect("/login")
        return check_login
```

But error found when debugging at this line

```
if self.check_user_logged_in:
```

with error
    raise AttributeError(attr)

```
AttributeError: check_user_logged_in
```

How can i know exactly happened ? any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are applying the decorator `login_required` to the class `Settings`, so the decorator will be executed when a `Settings` instance is created.

When you try to create an instance of `Settings`, the `check_login` function inside `login_required` is called.  The arguments it receives are the values that are passed to `Setting`'s `__init__` method.  `check_login` then takes the first value that it has received as an argument and tries to access its `check_user_logged_in` attribute.  This value, whatever it is (probably a webapp2.Request object), doesn't have a `check_user_logged_in` attribute so the exception is raised.

This can be demonstrated without using the webapp2 framework:

```
class HealthPortRequestHandler(object):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        pass

    @property
    def check_user_logged_in(self):
        pass

    @staticmethod
    def login_required(handler):
        def check_login(self, *args, **kwargs):
            if self.check_user_logged_in:
                return handler(self, *args, **kwargs)
            else:
                raise RuntimeError('Not expecting to execute this')
        return check_login   


@HealthPortRequestHandler.login_required
class Settings(HealthPortRequestHandler):
    pass

>>> s = Settings('Hello')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "demo.py", line 14, in check_login
    if self.check_user_logged_in:
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'check_user_logged_in'

>>> s = Settings(5)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "demo.py", line 14, in check_login
    if self.check_user_logged_in:
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'check_user_logged_in'

>>> s = Settings('Hello', 5)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "deco.py", line 14, in check_login
    if self.check_user_logged_in:
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'check_user_logged_in'
```

So that's why you get the AttributeError.

To fix it, I'd suggest decorating the request handler's dispatch method instead of the class definition.  This way you can still make your checks before the request is handled, but with access to the fully initialised `Settings` instance.

Comment: But anyway, i fixed my code as your suggestion:

`class Settings(HealthPortRequestHandler):
    @HealthPortRequestHandler.login_required
    def get(self):
        self.render("account/settings.html")
`